# Events manager alternative text placeholder

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the Events manager plugin and i'm trying to use the alternative text in the settings to make a layout for my locations page but it's not showing. It always overwrites the text you type in to the admin panel.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the alternative text in the code itself instead of the admin panel.